# Conection of two routers

Tags: wireless-networking

I have wireless router Cisco Linksys E900 connected to modem, but I can't get the WiFi signal on the other side of my house. So I put there a second wireless router Asus RT-N10E and connected it with an internet cabel to may first wireless router Cisco. How I have to configure second Asus router?

Answer (score 1):

Connect Asus router to a LAN port from your Cisco router. Make sure you had disabled DHCP server on Asus router. Set IP address to range of Cisco's DHCP server (usually something between 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254)

For a WiFi setting, if you are using 2.4Ghz make sure you use only channels 1 6 or 11. These channels don't overlap. If you want seamless experience with WiFi (say, you move within the house and your device automaticaly choose better signal) make sure you use same SSID of WiFi (name of your WiFi) and same encryption (use WPA2-AES) and same passphrase on both routers.